# DirectX9, мировое преобразование

Tags: c, directx

Что пытаюсь сделать: перед выводом модели перемещаю мировое пространство в определённую точку, затем поворачиваю его на определённый угол. Но из кода всегда выполняется первая строка(т.е. D3DXMatrixTranslation, или, если поменять местами, то MatrixRotationY) и выполняется только одно преобразование. Подскажите, где конкретно я ошибаюсь? Спасибо.

```
    D3DXMATRIX trans;
    D3DXMatrixTranslation(&trans, 1.f, 50.f, 1.f); // передвигаем вверх
    D3DXMatrixRotationY(&trans, y); / поворачиваем на угол y(все в порядке, он в радианах, просто это аргумент функции)
    Device->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &trans); // применяем преобразование к устройству
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ситуация проста: следует получить отдельно матрицу вращения(rotate) и матрицу перемещения(trans). И их следует конкатенировать(перемножить):

```
D3DXMATRIX out;
D3DXMatrixMultiply(&out, &trans, &rotate);
```

И затем применить преобразование. Забыл о перемножении совсем..